# How to solve this ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve the following ODE?

$$2y^2dx+(x-y+1)^2dy = 0$$

Thanks

Comment: change variable $t = x+1$, then transforming into an equation about $u = y/t$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I already tried the suggestion above of Yimin. Maybe something in my calculations?

Comment: "Maybe something in my calculations?" Well, you should show your calculations...

Comment: @PierreCarre, from my experience, screenshots are not welcome here. Typing all drafts in latex is not realistic. However, if I'm wrong and screenshots are an option, please let me know. I will gladly share it here.

Comment: @user135172 Not realistic? You just need to take the time... People posting answers are literally going through the "unrealistic" process of converting their drafts into LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2y^2dx+(x-y+1)^2dy = 0$

$\Rightarrow 2y^2dt+(t-y)^2dy = 0$ (Taking, $x+1=t$)

$\Rightarrow 2+\frac{(t-y)^2}{ y^2}\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$

$\Rightarrow 2+\frac{(1-\frac yt)^2}{ {(\frac yt})^2}\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$

Now,let $u=\frac yt $

$\Rightarrow tu=y $

$\Rightarrow u+t \frac {du }{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore 2+\frac{(1-u)^2}{ u^2}(u+t \frac {du }{dt} )= 0$

$\Rightarrow (2+\frac{(1-u)^2}{ u} )+ \frac{(1-u)^2}{ u^2} t \frac {du }{dt}=0$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{1+u^2}{ u} )+ \frac{(1-u)^2}{ u^2} t \frac {du }{dt}=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{(1+u^2)u}{ (1-u)^2} + t \frac {du }{dt}=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{(1+u^2)u}{ (1-u)^2} =- t \frac {du }{dt}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dt}t=-\frac{(1-u)^2}{(1+u^2)u}du$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dt}t=(\frac{2}{1+u^2}-\frac{1}{u})du$

Hope,now you can solve it.